# Get "Microsoft Excel has stopped working" message

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running MS Office 2010 on Windows 7 Professional.

I’ve been experiencing this problem periodically for the last month or so, not all the time, but probably once or twice a week.

I’m working on the VBA portion of a fairly complex workbook.  I start the day by making a copy of the previous day’s workbook, and make any subsequent code changes on the copy.  When I’m finished I’ll run VBA Code Cleaner, do a Debug, Save then exit Excel.  I also save a backup copy.  I’ll then reopen & close both of these workbooks a number of times just to satisfy myself that everything is still working.

The next day I’ll wake the computer and try to open these files, and as soon as the VBA code starts to run I’ll get the “Microsoft Excel has stopped working” message.  This can happen to either the main file or the backup file, and sometimes both.

If I open the bad file with the shift key down, I can get into the VBE area OK, but when I do a Debug or try to run VBA Code Cleaner I get the same message.

The only way I’ve found to recover from this is to:

1. Manually export the code
2. Save the file as an xlsx file, thus expunging all the code.
3. Save the xlsx file as a new xlsm/xlsb file, and then import the exported code.

I just today found another way to recover is to save the file as “xls”, then re-save as xlsb/xlsm, that somehow seems to “clean” something.

After the recovery everything is fine again, at least for a few days.
What I’ve tried so far:

1. Searched the internet, including StackOverflow, for possible solution.
2. Run various virus checkers (MS Essentials, Malwarebytes, SuperAntiSpyware)
3. Repaired MS Office 2010.
4. Uninstalled and re-installed MS Office 2010
5. Removed all add-ins
6. Uninstalled  Dropbox
7. Started using a new user profile.

I came across several articles that suggested xlsb files were prone to corruption, so I started saving as xlsm files.  Everything went well for about a week, and I thought I’d resolved the problem.  However, it’s now started happening with the xlsm files too, so I’m back to square one.

I’m running out of ideas - the next thing I might try would be re-installing Windows 7, but I really hope to avoid doing that!  I would really appreciate any suggestions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I believe I may have found my problem.  I noticed that one of my class objects wasn't always terminating correctly, due to it being referenced in a different class.  I fixed that, and now it's been 11 days without any problem (touch wood).  So I'm reasonably confident that this was the root cause.  But I must admit I'm still not quite sure why this occasionally corrupted the workbook.